# 7z "Incorrect command line" when I run the script in a different drive than C:

Tags: batch-file, 7zip

I'm doing a batch script so I can compress multiple directories inside a specific folder.

The thing is it works perfectly if the folder is at C:\something, but if I try to do the same to a folder in i.e E:\something, I get an error.

The script is this:

```
@ECHO OFF
if %1.==. (
    SET "rootpath=%cd%"
) else (
    SET "rootpath=%~1"
)
FOR /D %%D IN ("%rootpath%\*") DO (
  7za a -t7z %%D.7z %%D\* -mx9
)
```

Example of how it works normally:

```
C:\Users\Me\Desktop\ExampleFolder>script
7-Zip (A) 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
Scanning
Creating archive C:\Users\Me\Desktop\ExampleFolder\D1.7z
Everything is Ok
7-Zip (A) 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
Scanning
Creating archive C:\Users\Me\Desktop\ExampleFolder\D2.7z
Everything is Ok
```

Example of how it fails:

```
C:\Users\Me\ExampleFolder>script "E:\Documents\ExampleFolder"
Error:
Incorrect command line
Error:
Incorrect command line
```

Of course, I also tried to execute the script in the same folder and I checked that it works when I pass the location as an argument. Thanks.

Comment: Print `%%D` in your loop and see what it's trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 mistakes in the batch code.

The first one is not making sure that path assigned to `rootpath` does not end with a backslash resulting in `%%D` containing a path with two successive backslashes.

Two successive backslashes in path caused by this coding omission mistake depends on parameter string on calling the batch or when the batch file is executed from root of a drive because in this case `%cd%` expands to a path consisting of drive letter, a colon and a backslash. `%cd%` expands to a path without a backslash at end if current directory is not root directory of a drive. However, this mistake is not critical.

The second one is the real problem on using a directory path containing a critical character like a **space** or one of these characters: `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ ``

`%%D.7z` and `%%D\*` are not enclosed in double quotes making the parameters list for `7za.exe` invalid especially with 1 or more spaces in path.

How I found that out?

I inserted command `echo` left of `7za` to see what would be executed in the loop. I don't have 7-Zip installed and therefore needed the `echo` to test the batch file.

The solution:

```
@echo off
if "%~1" == "" (
    set "RootPath=%CD%"
) else (
    set "RootPath=%~1"
)
if "%RootPath:~-1%" == "\" set "RootPath=%RootPath:~0,-1%"

for /D %%D in ("%RootPath%\*") do (
    7za.exe a -t7z "%%D.7z" "%%D\*" -mx9
)
```

If this batch file is executed on always the same computer where path to `7za.exe` is known, it would be good to specify `7za.exe` with full path enclosed in double quotes in the batch file.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `cmd /?` ... read at least the last paragraph on last output help page.
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`

Answer (score 1):

Give a try for this batch file :

```
@echo off
set rootpath=c:\test
set strProgramFiles=%ProgramFiles%
if exist "%ProgramFiles(x86)%" set strProgramFiles=%ProgramFiles(x86)%
Set Path7z="%strProgramFiles%\7-zip\7z.exe"
echo %Path7z%
pause
CD /D "%rootpath%"
FOR /D %%D IN ("%rootpath%\*") DO (
  %Path7z% a -t7z %%D.7z %%D\* -mx9
)
pause
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a bit different to what I had in mind but I'll give it a try anyway.