# How to use a batch file to loop through several executables files to compress them (.7z) and rename the file to avoid ".exe.7z"

Tags: batch-file, cmd, zip, 7zip

I'm trying to zip up 27 exe files in one go using a batch file. The purpose of this file is to create .7z files for a modified HBCD menu. This file is located in, ...\Documents\CD\HBCD\Programs the exe files are in ...\Documents\CD\HBCD\Programs\Files\SysinternalsSuite

I keep getting:

```
Error:
Incorrect command line
```

I keep searching around and trying different things but I can't get it to work.

#### File Name: 7zBatch.bat

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
pushd "%~dp0"
echo "-------------------------------------------------"
echo "||======== BATCH ZIPPER (.7z) for HBCD ========||"
echo "-------------------------------------------------"

:AskSource
echo Enter the location of the exe file(s)
set SOURCE=
set /p SOURCE=">>" %=%
echo "%SOURCE%", is that correct & goto ConfirmSource

:ConfirmSource
echo (Y)es or (N)o?
set INPUT=
set /p INPUT=">>" %=%
if /I "%INPUT%"=="y" goto AskDest
if /I "%INPUT%"=="n" goto AskSource
echo Incorrect input, is the location correct? & goto ConfirmSource

:AskDest
cd %SOURCE%
echo Enter the location of the zip file(s)
set DEST=
set /p DEST=">>" %=%
echo "%DEST%", is that correct & goto ConfirmDest

:ConfirmDest
echo (Y)es or (N)o?
set INPUT=
set /p INPUT=">>" %=%
if /I "%INPUT%"=="y" goto Execute
if /I "%INPUT%"=="n" goto AskDest
echo Incorrect input, is the location correct? & goto ConfirmDest

:Execute
 FOR /f "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b *.exe') DO (
 set fname=%%G
 set nfname=!fname:.exe=!
 echo.
 echo Found: !fname!

 ..\..\7z.exe a -t7z !nfname!.7z "!fname!" -mx5 -sdel -oC:%DEST%
 timeout /t 10 /nobreak
 )
ENDLOCAL
echo.
pause
```

Once it gets to the 7 Zip line it gives the error. I realized that the **nfname** variable was empty so I tried:

```
set nfname=!%%G:.exe=!
```

That didn't work so I tried deleting that and going with:

```
..\..\7z.exe a -t7z !fname:.exe=!.7z "!fname!" -mx5 -sdel -oC:%DEST%
```

That didn't work so I tried putting different things in quotes one by one and then everything:

```
"..\..\7z.exe" a -t7z "!fname:.exe=!.7z" "!fname!" -mx5 -sdel -oC:"%DEST%"
```

Still nothing. What am I missing?

Comment: Try [inserting `echo` before the 7z call command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38411592/7z-incorrect-command-line-when-i-run-the-script-in-a-different-drive-than-c).

Comment: I don't know what your problem is but I would highly suggest you open up a command prompt and type: `for /?`.  Read the last section about the modifiers you can use with the `FOR` variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL
echo "-------------------------------------------------"
echo "||======== BATCH ZIPPER (.7z) for HBCD ========||"
echo "-------------------------------------------------"

:AskSource
echo Enter the location of the exe file(s)
set "SOURCE="
set /p "SOURCE=>>"
echo "%SOURCE%", is that correct

:ConfirmSource
echo (Y)es or (N)o?
set "INPUT="
set /p "INPUT=>>"
if /I "%INPUT%"=="y" goto AskDest
if /I "%INPUT%"=="n" goto AskSource
echo Incorrect input, is the location correct?
goto ConfirmSource

:AskDest
echo Enter the location of the zip file(s)
set "DEST="
set /p "DEST=>>"
echo "%DEST%", is that correct

:ConfirmDest
echo (Y)es or (N)o?
set "INPUT="
set /p "INPUT=>>"
if /I "%INPUT%"=="y" goto Execute
if /I "%INPUT%"=="n" goto AskDest
echo Incorrect input, is the location correct?
goto ConfirmDest

:Execute
FOR %%G IN ("%SOURCE%\*.exe") DO (
    "%~dp0..\..\7z.exe" a -t7z "%DEST%\%%~nG.7z" "%%~fG" -mx5 -sdel
)
ENDLOCAL
echo.
pause
```

The `pushd` and `cd` removed. Unsure why `7z.exe` would be
located 2 directories up from where the input executable
directory is located. `7z.exe` is now located 2 directories
up from the script directory.

The `-o` switch for `7z.exe` is only for extraction as
mentioned in the help file so is omitted.

Double quoted `set` of variables to avoid any trailing spaces.

The `for` loop changed to simple type as it gives the file
paths required without need of using `dir`.

`EnableDelayedExpansion` removed as the `for` variables
uses modifiers to get fullpath, name, drive etc. See
`for /?` about modifiers available.

Removed `timeout` as it complains if stdin is used and see
no reason to use it for this task.

Removed obsolete `goto` commands that go to the next line
with a command.